# How to list all ECR repositories with no lifecycle policy set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, elastic-container-registry

I need to find all ECR repositories which have no lifecycle policy set to them, I tried using `aws ecr describe-repositories` and using `--filters` but the command output doesn't include lifecycle policies ([aws docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/describe-repositories.html)).
What would be the correct command to use?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `--filters` parameter in the API of `describe-repository`. Instead you need to call `get-repository-policy` to retrieve this information ([docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/get-repository-policy.html)).